# Batch Drawable Importer plugin not working in android 4.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-drawable-importer

I am using android studio version 4.0.1. I am trying to use the Batch Drawable Importer, but it does not work well. It is not taking or adding images when I click the + Button. **How to add an image into this Importer?**

Comment: You should post your code so other can see what you are doing and perhaps determine what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have struggled through it too. As it turns out, by Android Studio 3.6.1 this plugin began to not work anymore. As of now, you can use Android Assets studios over the web, like [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example) one.